# render_to_string doesn't work as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use `render_to_string` by its default nature in my console..

```
StoresController.new.render_to_string '/shared/colors'
```

This returns :

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template /shared/colors with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip, :srt], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :haml]}. Searched in:
  * "/Sites/whisper.me/app/views"
  * "/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@project/gems/teaspoon-0.7.7/app/views"
  * "/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@project/gems/devise-2.2.2/app/views"
  * "/Sites/project"
  * "/"
```

Even though **my partial** is clearly there. In fact, if I have it search for any file in any directory with any controller, it also doesn't work as expected. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
StoresController.new.render_to_string partial: '/shared/colors'
```

Give `partial` option as you are trying to render a partial.

Comment: Glad to help. Don't forget to accept the answer when time out is over. :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `'/shared/colors'` should work? Following [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render) I would try the following instead:

```
StoresController.new.render_to_string 'shared/colors'
```

The leading slash seems to determine a file system path:

> The render method can also use a view that's entirely outside of your application [...]. Rails determines that this is a file render because of the leading slash character.